# Issues with initializing service class that has dependency on running application on startup (play 2.4 / scala)

Tags: scala, playframework, quartz-scheduler

I am currently digging into using Quartz in our play 2.4 application.
Initially, I tried initializing everything through `Global` object, and everything worked perfectly.

Now, I an trying to move away from `Global` utilize modules infrastructure.
Here is what I have until now.

**JobSchedulingService**

```
@Singleton
class JobSchedulingService @Inject()(lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) extends ClassLogger{

  lazy val schedulerFactory = current.injector.instanceOf[StdSchedulerFactory]

  lazy val scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler

  /**
    * Let's make sure that scheduler shuts down properly
    */
  lifecycle.addStopHook{ () =>
    Future.successful{
      if (scheduler.isStarted) {
        scheduler.shutdown(true)
      }
    }
  }

  protected def init() : Unit = {
    logger.info("Initializing scheduler...")
    scheduler.start()
  }

  init()
}
```

**SchedulerModule** -  here for initialization of the service above.

```
class SchedulerModule extends AbstractModule{
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[JobSchedulingService]).asEagerSingleton
  }
}
```

And in my `application.conf` I added:

```
play.modules.enabled += "scheduling.modules.SchedulerModule"
```

It looks pretty strait forward. However, when the app starts I am getting an exception:

> 2016-03-23 00:07:42,173 INFO  s.JobSchedulingService - Initializing
>   scheduler... 2016-03-23 00:07:42,213 ERROR application -
>
> ! @6pfp72mh6 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
>
> play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CreationException:
>   Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
>
> 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: There is
>   no started application   at
>   scheduling.JobSchedulingService.(JobSchedulingService.scala:15) 
>   at
>   scheduling.modules.SchedulerModule.configure(SchedulerModule.scala:11)
>   (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule ->
>   scheduling.modules.SchedulerModule)   while locating
>   scheduling.JobSchedulingService
>
> ...

The thing is, in our app, the scheduler is based of off persistence job storage and should restart when the application restarts. Again, when I did it through `Global`, it worked perfectly.

How do I get around this problem? What is the correct way to initialize an instance on startup?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be using the dependency injection for everything. Inject the scheduler like..

```
class JobSchedulingService @Inject()(lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle, schedulerFactory: StdSchedulerFactory) extends ClassLogger{
  lazy val scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler
```

Comment: But that is exactly what this is doing: `current.injector.instanceOf[StdSchedulerFactory]`. And that is exactly what does not work before the application gets fully initialized.

Comment: This is actually also worked. Then, I am not sure I fully understand how this works then. But, thank for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...
I think I just resolved it.

It seems like the problem was not the actual initialization of a class, but this line:

```
lazy val schedulerFactory = current.injector.instanceOf[StdSchedulerFactory]
```

once I changed it to:

```
lazy val schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory
```

it started working.

May that will help somebody